# WPF Image Authority/Host could not be parsed for one image

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, uri

I created a WPF application in visual studio 2010 a couple of weeks ago and have used several resourced images for building the app.

Today I go in to check it and 1 of my images throws up the above error. All my images are loaded the same way from a shared drive using the associated drive letter. None of the other images throw up this error.

I am just not sure why only this one image is causing a problem. All my images are png files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that has worked for me.

I reloaded the image back in from scratch and reset my visual studio environment settings which appears to have fixed it at least for now.  If anyone has any better (more permanent) solutions please feel free to post.